# How to obtain two successive elements in an enhanced for loop in java?

Tags: java, xml, foreach

I have an enhanced for loop in which I am iterating over a NodeList as

```
String nodename = null;
for(node node : nodeList) {
   nodename = node.getNodeName();
    ...
    ...
}
```

Here I have a problem. I want to compare two successive nodenames in the nodeList during iteration and return if they are found same.

How to obtain two successive elements in the enhanced for loop ?

Please help me out. I am using DOM parsing strategy.

Comment: do you mind changing the extended for loop to a normal for loop. then you can get any value based on the index.

Comment: Then you wouldn't use a for-each loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get two consecutive elements within that scope with fast enumeration.

Use an `Iterator` instead:

```
Iterator<Node> i = nodeList.iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
    Node next = i.next();
    Node following = null;
    if (i.hasNext()) {
        following = i.next();
    }
}
```

Or, as suggested by vikeng21, use a normal `for` loop and compare next index with `List`'s size to avoid `IndexOutOfBoundsException`s.

Answer (score 0):

```
String lastNode    = null;

for (Node n : nodeList) {
    if (n.equals(lastNode)
        return n;

    lastNode = n;
}
```